# PS invoke command and net use

Tags: powershell, windows-10

when i tried to use Invoke-Command with Net use to remove mapped drive for specyfic PC nothing happens

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName PCNAME -ScriptBlock { NET USE * /d /y}
```

It says that there are no entries in the list but they clearly are (i am opening powershell ISE as domain admin). What i am doing wrong  ?

Both Machines are on Win 10

Regards

Comment: Mapped drives are per-user. This really sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). What are you really needing to do?

Comment: I want to remove mapped drive for users  who were disabled but they have not logged out yet

Comment: But why? What does this fix?

Comment: Some leavers can not return laptops for obvious reasons

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean ("leavers"?) or how that answers my question. Why do you think you need to unmap these drives? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: when we disable account in AD - if someone wont log out user has access to mapped drive (for example personal drive) . The problem is that since some people are on quaranteen they cannot reurn their equipment , untill it ends. So I am tryng to figure it out how to prevent that situation, that is why i want to remove mapped drives.

Comment: I think the issue you are having is if the user connects to the network drive and then the account is disable the user still can access the drive.  Disable the user account then restart the computer or force a log off.  They should not have access to the mapped drives. OPTION TWO: disable the user account then go on the servers with the mapped drives and kick them off.  They should not be able to reconnect with a disabled account.

Comment: @Wiktor On your file server, add the disabled user with access denied to the folders you share. This will take effect immediately, because ACLs are evaluated at every access and a deny has the highest priority. The kerberos ticket instead, will stay for probably 10 more hours (default). That's why disabling the account is not sufficient in your case.